# Strange Legend Layout on Fieldset

Tags: html, legend, fieldset

Why does the legend 'Description' appear *below* the border of the second fieldset?

Both fieldsets seem symmetrical to me (for now).

[image]

EDIT: javascript code and jsfiddle link

```
NounEditor = function() {
var nc = {}; //private members
nc.DIV = $('<form/>');

var nameFieldSet = $('<fieldset/>').appendTo(nc.DIV);
nameFieldSet.append($('<legend/>', {text: 'Name'}));

for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    var nameDiv = $('<div/>', {text: "lang" + i })
    .append($('<input/>', {
        style: 'display: inline-block'}));
    nameFieldSet.append(nameDiv);
}
nc.DIV.append($('<p/>'));
var descFieldSet=$('<fieldset/>').appendTo(nc.DIV);
descFieldSet.append($('<lengend/>', {text: 'Description'}));
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    var descDiv = $('<div/>', {text: "lang" + i })
    .append($('<input/>', {
        style: 'display: inline-block'}));
    descFieldSet.append(descDiv);
}

nc.DLG = nc.DIV.dialog({
    title: 'noun editor',
    modal: false, autoOpen: false,
    close: function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

this.show=function(){
    nc.DLG.dialog('open');
}

} // class NounEditor

var dlg = new NounEditor();
dlg.show();
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7tJ9/)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue at jsfiddle? It works fine for me.

Comment: Added. Can it be related to dynamically adding html elements by jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've spelled `legend` incorrectly, meaning it isn't being given default styling by the browser:

```
<lengend>Description</lengend>
```

In your JavaScript you need to change:

```js
 descFieldSet.append($('<lengend/>', {text: 'Description'}));
```

To:

```js
 descFieldSet.append($('<legend/>', {text: 'Description'}));
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7tJ9/1/).